# Sound come always from speakers

Tags: sound, headphones

i ended up here because i googled for almost all day but i didn't find a solution for my problem: I'm on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 17.10, when i insert the headphone jack the audio still output from speakers (nothing come from headphone) and is stronger, when there is no headphone jack inserted my speakers are listed as "line out - internal audio" and when I insert the jack it becomes "analog headphones - internal audio". I'm on a desktop machine. I also tried using Ubuntu 16.04 same thing and I'm 100% sure that nothing is broken because on Windows works well. Hope that you guys can help me, thanks you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Plug in your headphones, click on the "Sound" icon on your bottom panel, click on "sound settings", on the "Device" box, you should have "Speakers" and "Headphones", click on "Headphones", sound should come out of your headphones now.

Comment: The problem is really here, when i go in devices, it shows "Line out" if the headphone jack is not connected, if i connect the jack "Line out" disappears and "Headphones" takes his place and even if i select the "Headphones" options the sound come from the same speaker. Ps: I got a good amount of experience with Ubuntu, i always fixed my problem spending a bit of time on Google, this is the first time that i didn't find a solution

Comment: what do you see in alsamixer? are headphones unmuted and not set to 0. is auto-mute enabled for sound device switching? are you checking audio settings only from panel applet or have you checked in pavucontrol?